# amplitude-phase modulation equations solution

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following equation

```
σ = 0.05;
f = 0.5;
μ = 0.1;
a[0] == 1
γ[0] == 0


γ'[t] == σ - 3/8 a[t]^2 + f/(2 a[t]) Cos[γ[t]]

a'[t] == -μ a[t] + f/2  Sin[γ[t]]
```

Unfortunately Mathematica is unable to do so. Is there a way to obtain the much needed solution ?

Comment: Does this give something close to what you need: `funcs = NDSolveValue[{\[Gamma]'[t] == \[Sigma] - 3/8 a[t]^2 + f/(2 a[t]) Cos[\[Gamma][t]],  a'[t] == -\[Mu] a[t] + f/2 Sin[\[Gamma][t]], a[0] == 1, \[Gamma][0] == 0}, {\[Gamma], a}, {t, 0, 30}]; Plot[Evaluate@Through@funcs@t, {t, 0, 30}]`?

Comment: I am looking for exactly that.Thank you.

Comment: posted the comment as answer. Welcome to mma.se.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 3):

```
funcs = NDSolveValue[{γ'[t] == σ - 3/8 a[t]^2 + f/(2 a[t]) Cos[γ[t]], 
   a'[t] == -μ a[t] + f/2 Sin[γ[t]],
   a[0] == 1, γ[0] == 0}, {γ, a}, {t, 0, 30}]; 

Plot[Evaluate@Through@funcs@t, {t, 0, 30}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I believe that it is this solution that you want to:

```
DSolve[Derivative[1][a][t] == -0.1 a[t] + 0.25 Sin[γ[t]], {a[t]}, {t}]
```

> [image]